"The application did not respond" but embed was still sent
enter image description here
Okay so, as you can see embed is being sent correctly but I still get "The application did not respond". As you may know this message dissapears after X time automatically, but I would like that message not to be shown.
This is the code:
@tree.command(name="scalp")
@app_commands.describe(action = "Buy/Close/Trim/Average")
@app_commands.describe(ticker = "Ticker")
@app_commands.describe(type = "Call/Put")
@app_commands.describe(strike = "Strike Price")
@app_commands.describe(price="Entry Price")
@app_commands.describe(notes="Notes")
async def scalp(message: discord.Interaction, action: str, ticker: str, type: str, strike: str, price: str, notes: str):

    if(action == "buy" or action == "Buy" or action == "BUY"):
        color= 0x2ecc71
    elif(action == "sell" or action == "Sell" or action == "SELL"):
        color= 0xe74c3c
    else:
        color= 0xe67e22

    #emojis
    white_check_mark = ":white_check_mark:"  
    scissors = ":scissors:"
    close_trade = ":red_circle:"
    average = ":bar_chart:"

    if(action.lower() == "buy"):
        title = f"NEW ENTRY {white_check_mark}"
        
    elif(action.lower() == "sell"):
        title = f"CLOSE CONTRACT {close_trade}"
        
    elif(action.lower() == "trim"):
        title = f"TRIM CONTRACT {scissors}"
        
    elif(action.lower() == "average"):
        title = f"AVERAGE CONTRACT {average}"
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{title}", description=f"**Contract**: {ticker}\n\n **Strike**: ${strike}\n\n **Type**: {type} \n\n**Contract price**: {price}\n\n**Notes**: {notes}", color=color)
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    timestamp = timestamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Informational Purposes Only, Not Financial Advice.\nPlease manage your risk and position size according to your own risk tolerance • {timestamp}", icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/..")
    #embed.set_author(name="SOLARIS OPTIONS", icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/...")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/...")
    print("Embed sent..")

    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

